# Can not rerecord a oni file

Tags: java, openni

I try to record oni files with Java. It works good when I record one file. But when I want to record several files I run into problems.

Here is some test code:

```
package test;

import org.OpenNI.Context;
import org.OpenNI.DepthGenerator;
import org.OpenNI.GeneralException;
import org.OpenNI.ImageGenerator;
import org.OpenNI.OutArg;
import org.OpenNI.RecordMedium;
import org.OpenNI.Recorder;
import org.OpenNI.ScriptNode;

public class RecorderProblems {

    private static final String SAMPLE_XML_FILE = "KinectConfig.xml";
    private static final String TEST1_ONI_FILE = "Test1.oni";
    private static final String TEST2_ONI_FILE = "Test2.oni";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = null;
        DepthGenerator depthGenerator = null;
        ImageGenerator imageGenerator = null;
        try {
            OutArg<ScriptNode> scriptNode = new OutArg<ScriptNode>();

            // Init Hardware
            System.out.println("Init Hardware");
            context = Context.createFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_FILE, scriptNode);
            depthGenerator = DepthGenerator.create(context);
            imageGenerator = ImageGenerator.create(context);
            context.startGeneratingAll();

            // Record 1
            System.out.println("Start Record 1");
            Recorder recorder = Recorder.create(context, "oni");
            // Adding next line produces a corrupt file, but the program runs fine
//          context.createProductionTree(recorder.getInfo());
            recorder.setDestination(RecordMedium.FILE, TEST1_ONI_FILE);
            recorder.addNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
            recorder.addNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                context.waitOneUpdateAll(imageGenerator);
                recorder.Record();
            }
            recorder.removeNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
            recorder.removeNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
            recorder.dispose();

            // Record 2
            System.out.println("Start Record 2");
            recorder = Recorder.create(context, "oni");
            // Adding next line produces a corrupt file, but the program runs fine
//          context.createProductionTree(recorder.getInfo());
            recorder.setDestination(RecordMedium.FILE, TEST2_ONI_FILE);
            recorder.addNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
            recorder.addNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                context.waitOneUpdateAll(imageGenerator);
                recorder.Record();
            }
            recorder.removeNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
            recorder.removeNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
            recorder.dispose();
        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // End Hardware
            System.out.println("End Hardware");
            depthGenerator.dispose();
            depthGenerator = null;
            imageGenerator.dispose();
            imageGenerator = null;
            context.release();
            context.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to set the destination for the second record I get a StatusException "Input pointer is null".

If I add the uncommented line, the program runs fine, but the created oni files are not readable. (I do not know exactly what the line does.)

I also tried to reinitialize the context. At first this worked fine, but when I tried to record several files I had problems at reinitialization, too. Here is some sample code:

```
package test;

import org.OpenNI.Context;
import org.OpenNI.DepthGenerator;
import org.OpenNI.GeneralException;
import org.OpenNI.ImageGenerator;
import org.OpenNI.OutArg;
import org.OpenNI.RecordMedium;
import org.OpenNI.Recorder;
import org.OpenNI.ScriptNode;

public class RecorderProblems {

    private static final String SAMPLE_XML_FILE = "KinectConfig.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Context context = null;
        DepthGenerator depthGenerator = null;
        ImageGenerator imageGenerator = null;
        try {
            OutArg<ScriptNode> scriptNode = new OutArg<ScriptNode>();

            // Record 1
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                System.out.println("Run " + i);
                // Init Hardware
                System.out.println("Init Hardware " + i);
                context = Context
                        .createFromXmlFile(SAMPLE_XML_FILE, scriptNode);
                depthGenerator = DepthGenerator.create(context);
                imageGenerator = ImageGenerator.create(context);
                context.startGeneratingAll();

                System.out.println("Start Record " + i);
                Recorder recorder = Recorder.create(context, "oni");
                recorder.setDestination(RecordMedium.FILE, "test_" + i + ".oni");
                recorder.addNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
                recorder.addNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    context.waitOneUpdateAll(imageGenerator);
                    recorder.Record();
                }
                recorder.removeNodeToRecording(depthGenerator);
                recorder.removeNodeToRecording(imageGenerator);
                recorder.dispose();

                System.out.println("End Hardware " + i);
                depthGenerator.dispose();
                depthGenerator = null;
                imageGenerator.dispose();
                imageGenerator = null;
                context.release();
                context.dispose();
            }

        } catch (GeneralException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the third run I got a StatusExcption "A timeout has occurred when waiting for new data!".

Has anybody experience with recording of files? I do not know if, I use the library wrong, or if this is a problem of OpenNI (with Java)?

By the way I use OpenNI 1.5.2.23 and the Kinect camera. The XML configuration file "KinectConfig.xml" is the default XML file which is shipped with the OpenNI samples. I just renamed it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making it so complicated?
You can **use [Android libraries](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html)** for that.

Comment: I need the oni file format. The created oni files should be processed with a existing library which need oni files as input. I think this library does not support oni, or I have overread it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem of reading VGA resolution depth and rgb betting the same timeout error. If i reduce the resolution of either depth or rgb to quarter vga everything works.